# Updating state with timer does not return updated values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I'm new to unit testing with Jest. The project has a progress indicator component that uses setInterval as a timer. I need to unit test that the "completed" state variable is updating correctly on 20ms ticks in the "progress" function.

```
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
"react-scripts": "^2.1.3"
```

progress.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

const styles = theme => ({
  progress: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  }
});

class CircularDeterminate extends React.Component {
  state = {
    completed: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.progress, 20);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  progress = () => {
    let be = this.state.completed;
    console.log('>>>>>> ', this.state.completed);
    const { completed } = this.state;
    this.setState({ completed: completed >= 100 ? 0 : completed + 1 });
    console.log('+++++ ', be, '  ', this.state.completed);
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    if (!this.props.statusCode) {
      return (
        <div>
          <CircularProgress
            className={classes.progress}
            variant="determinate"
            value={this.state.completed}
          />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

CircularDeterminate.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CircularDeterminate);
```

progressTest.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Progress from '../progress';

describe('Input Component', () => {
  it('update timer', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const wrapper = mount(<Progress />);
    wrapper.instance().setState({ completed: 8 });

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(41);
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.instance().state.completed).toBe(10);
  });
});
```

The above test fails with: Expected: 10, Received: 8. I would expect "completed" to be of value 10 after 2 ticks (~41 ms).

Answer (score 0):

One issue in the above code (which may or may not be the actual problem depending on how Jest's fake timers work, but is certainly **a** problem) is you're breaking one of the fundamental rules of React state: Since [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), if you're setting new state *based on existing state*, you **must** use the calback form of `setState`. So this is incorrect:

```
const { completed } = this.state;
this.setState({ completed: completed >= 100 ? 0 : completed + 1 });
console.log('+++++ ', be, '  ', this.state.completed);
```

this is the correct form:

```
this.setState(
    ({completed}) => ({
        completed: completed >= 100 ? 0 : completed + 1
    }),
    () => {
        console.log('+++++ ', be, '  ', this.state.completed);
    }
);
```

Comment: State updates are async, is that also the reason why the state in the unit test isn't updating right away?

Comment: @user2251234 - I don't use jest, so I don't know how jest's fake timers work, but the esting code does look synchronous, which wouldn't be correct. I know I've seen async jest testing, so it's just a matter of looking up how that part is done.